# Scraper using www::mechanize

Tags: perl, web-scraping, mechanize

I am writting my first scraper in perl and I have some problems. I thought that when I submit a form is always a post request. But I have this website I want to get data from and it appears that has only get methods even if it has a form in it.
Also I don't know how to submit the form, it has fields with dropdown menu to select values.

Can anyone help me with some ideas? So far I managed to set up a connection to the URL and get its content. I'm stuck.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
 
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;
 
my $homepage = 'http://bacalaureat.edu.ro//';
my $source;
 
my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$browser->agent_alias('Windows Mozilla');
$browser->get($homepage);

if ($browser->success()) {
    $source = $browser->content();
    print "Page Source: \n\n\n" . $source . "\n\n\n";
} else {
    print "Could not access $homepage! Status: " . $browser->status() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your code sample does not include any attempts to submit any forms.

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do, I know I have to use `submit_form` but I don't know how to do it, with what parameters..

Answer (score 0):

There is no  tag on this page and there is no submit. This page just redirects you to the URL: `/Pages/JudetRezultAlfa.aspx?jud=$ID` there `$ID` is the value of *selJud* field.

So all you need is to parse HTML (to get values of selJud) and next `$mech->get("http://bacalaureat.edu.ro/Pages/JudetRezultAlfa.aspx?jud=" . $ID)` using *selJud* you want.

Answer (score 0):

The [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) module wants to act like a browser. Instead of thinking of low-level operations, think about the logical tasks you are doing.

In the first example in its documentation, it navigates to a page with `get` to prime the chain. Then, it decides to do things with the current page it is on, such as `follow_link` or `submit_form`. You don't worry about how it does that because it figures it out for you:

```
use WWW::Mechanize ();
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
 
$mech->get( $url );
 
$mech->follow_link( n => 3 );
$mech->follow_link( text_regex => qr/download this/i );
$mech->follow_link( url => 'http://host.com/index.html' );
 
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 3,
    fields      => {
        username    => 'mungo',
        password    => 'lost-and-alone',
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to load a page with a form on it, fill in the input elements and submit it.

Typically, you'll load it up in a browser, and then write code to mimic what you'd do form the keyboard.

Comment: Ok, and how can I see the name of fields and what values are assigned when I submit the form from a browser?

Comment: Using your browser's development tools option.  Right click on a form element and choose 'inspect'.